# How to override built-in Excel exporting functionality in AG Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

AG Grid has built-in functionality for exporting a grid of data down to an Excel-friendly format: `*xls`, `*.xlsx`, `*.csv`, etc. The button that does this appears when you click it from a context menu that appears on a right-click over the grid.

I'd like to add `processCellCallback()` functionality to this link in the context menu, but all the docs, tutorials, SO answers, etc. say that I would have to create a brand new button to do this. In other words, it looks like I can't can config `processCellCallback()` to work from the grid's built-in context menu.

Am I correct here?

thx in advance

Comment: Probably that's the only possibility. Debugging the vendor.js showed, that calling the menu button calls the `exportDataAsExcel` function with a hardcoded param, only holding a constant for the export-mode

Answer (score 4):

Ok, since no answers till now I try to help: 
I think there is no real possibility for that.

I went trhough the code by debugging and realized: The basic export-button just calls the `exportDataAsExcel` function, handing over no variables. No pass-through of anything you give the grid.

Best guess if you really need the export through the context menu:
[Create it yourself](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/)...

Since most entries can be re-created with a string in the menu-definition it is not that hard. However: if the basic menu changes yours wont...